# infix to postfix without loops inside loops

Tags: java, nested-loops

So i have an assignment to write infix to postfix method without any nested loops (loops in loops) and i didn't notice that and i wrote long method with nested loops, any idea how to fix it? here is the code
How can i divide them into smaller method while have stack?

```
List<String> infix2Postfix(List<String> infix) {
        Stack<String> opStack = new Stack<>();
        List<String> outPut = new ArrayList<>();


        for (String inComing : infix) {
            // When incoming is  one of  -,+,*,/,^
            if (OPERATORS.contains(inComing)) {
                if (opStack.empty() || opStack.peek().equals("(")) {
                    ....
                } else {
                    ....
                    if (inComingP == 4 && inComingP == operatorP) {
                        ....
                    } else if (inComingP == operatorP) {
                       ...

                    } else if (inComingP < operatorP) {

                        while (!opStack.empty() && !opStack.peek().equals("(")) {
                          ...
                        }
                        opStack.push(inComing);

                    } else {
                        opStack.push(inComing);
                    }
                }

            }
            // when incoming is one of "(" , ")"
            else if ("()".contains(inComing)) {
                if (")".equals(inComing)) {

                    while (opStack.size() != 0 && !opStack.peek().equals("(")) {
                       ...
                    }
                    if (opStack.size() == 0) {
                        ...
                    } else {
                        opStack.pop(); 
                    }


                } else {
                    opStack.add(inComing);
                }

            } else {
                outPut.add(inComing);
            }

        }

        if (opStack.contains("(")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MISSING_OPERATOR);
        }
        while (!opStack.empty()) {

            outPut.add(opStack.pop());

        }
        return outPut;
    }
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible unless you are expected to use (i.e. have been taught) recursive descent. The classic Dijkstra Shunting-Yard Algorithm looks like this. I mean you could always refactor the inner loops into separate methods, and I guess it's possible that that is the point of the exercise, but it seems pretty futile to me. Only a madman would actually write it that way and obfuscate the relationship to Dijkstra. When I implement classic algorithms I stick as close as possible to my source.

Comment: Try making different funtions for inner loops and calling them instead of using that inner loop.

Comment: Thank you @user207421 ,yes i think the easiest way would be refactoring the inner loops into separate methods. my question is do i need to create stack for every method? i probably need 2 methods at least one for the operators and one for the parenthesis.

Comment: Of course not. You need a single stack.